# RecordMyDesktop exited with status 3204: Cannot connect to X Server

Tags: recordmydesktop

I'm trying to do a recording of my screen under Ubuntu 14.04 (Unity) with RecordMyDesktop. I'm posting here screenshots of its config. Also, I'm using dual monitor, and I want to select only one. So I selected it "as window". I tried giving the display as a command line argument, same result. I tried running as root, same result: "Cannot connect to X Server".

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And, this is what happens every time:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but the value for *Misc -> Display* might be the problem. You could try setting the appropriate value for the display you're trying to record.

This [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/230838/212123) should help you to check the available displays; with command:

```
w -hs | awk '{print $3}' | sort -u
```

For me the default value works which is `:0.0`

Comment: I will try. Selecting the monitor might solve, especially because i have two monitors hooked up.

Comment: @Bodo, didn't that help?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55709/how-to-select-display-to-record-in-recordmydesktop), it is not the display parameter, but the coordinates. Try something like

```
recordmydesktop --display=0 --width=1920 height=1080 --fps=15 --no-sound --delay=10
```

on the command line, with your correct values for width and height of course.